# How do I add an if statement to the postcondition of a schema?

Tags: if-statement, formal-methods, formal-verification, perfect-developer

I'll simplify things for this scenario (It's in Perfect Developer, it gets complex quite quickly). Let's say I have a simple schema in my class, called `Succeed`, which takes a `Course` (which is a previously defined class) as parameter.

Basically, I want to be sure that the course is in my courses `set` as a precondition, and then add it to my `coursesCompleted` set in my postcondition. This simple schema works great, and looks like this :

```
schema !Succeed(c:Course)
pre
    c in allCourses
post
    coursesCompleted! = coursesCompleted.append(c);
```

However, I want to add a quite simple `if` condition: If my coursesCompleted cardinality is 30 or more, I want to set a `Diplomation` enum to, let's say, "`Ok`". If the cardinality is less than 30, I will set it to "`NotOk`"

According to Perfect Developer's documentation, and all the rare examples I've seen, the `if` syntax should look like this :

```
if [condition1] : do stuff;
   [condition2] : do other stuff;
fi
```

However, if I plug that directly in my schema, as is :

```
schema !Succeed(c:Course)
pre
    c in allCourses
post
    coursesCompleted! = coursesCompleted.append(c),
    if [#coursesCompleted >= 30] : diplomation = Ok@DiplomationEnum;
       [#coursesCompleted < 30] : diplomation = NotOk@DiplomationEnum;
    fi
```

it does not work, I always end up with a "very descriptive"

> Error! Syntax error at keyword 'if', expected one of: '!' '(' '?'
>   'c_address_of'

I've tried adding some `;` everywhere, adding a `via` keyword after the `post`, changing it's position, trading `;`s with `,`, and a *lot* of other trial and error stuff.

So my question is: How can I add a `if` condition to a postcondition of a schema, in Perfect Developer?

Please answer in Perfect Developer. I (sadly) know my formal methods, I only need the `if` to compile in the worst tool in the world.

Answer (score 1):

I can provide a solution in formal-methods using the zet notation, since I am not using Perfect Developer, however, that program should be based on formal-methods. As far as I know in formal methods, if conditions are not used when the system has different behavior over some preconditions, but rather you create 2 methods with different
preconditions(the way i implemented it) or a nested method covering both scenarios, seperated with a Logic OR in between. When it comes to error handling, you first provide a best case scenario and then define a robust method definition(schema calculus).

In formal methods the notation ! is used to describe the output while ? is used for the input.

I hope that this will help you understand possible issues, since its not a direct perfect-developer solution. However, considering the fact that in formal methods mathematics are used, you can use the following specification and jump to any program/language for the implementation part.

Note that: Anything that you will see in the following schemata on the preconditions/how the system changes part, is connected with a logic AND, however I am not using the symbol because is implied as far as a logic OR is not used.

So here is how it will look like in formal-methods(Z-notation).

[image]